# what is the better way to handle the columns to return variable for SQLite database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this database method is returning only the string name from the KEY_NAME column of the database.  the other two columns are KEY_ROWID and KEY_HITS.

is it better to make the columns to return array variable like this;

```
 String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
```

because the only the column KEY_NAME is needed, or is it better to always put all the columns in like this;

```
 String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HITS };
```

full code for the database method shown below;

```
 public String getName(long l){
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HITS };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID +"="+ l, null, null, null, null);
if(c!= null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String name = c.getString(1);
    return name;
}
return null;
}
```

EDIT;

after some testing I found out that I can return only the single column name "KEY_NAME" if I am using this;

```
total = total + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)); // only need { KEY_NAME };
```

however, when I use the following code to use a number to get column position "c.getInt(2)" it does not work unless I return all three column names

```
total = total + c.getInt(2);   // requires {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HITS };
```

Comment: Your edit is wrong. But of course you must adapt the column index to the correct position within your projection. In this case your projection contains only one column, thus the index for this column must be `0`. `total = total + c.getInt(0);` would work flawlessly.

Comment: yes you are correct, i will use c.getInt(0) in that situation, by the way. i have been reading your blog on android "grokking android"  it is vary good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons, you should try to fetch as less column as necessary.

However, if you are using an CursorAdapter, you need the *id* column.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to get data that you don't need.

If you only want to get one column , query the database for that column only, and keep doing so as long as it works for you.